# sprintf (convert int to char[])

Tags: string, int, type-conversion, printf

In my program I try to convert a int to a char[20];

I try to do this in the following way:

```
  char str[20];    
  sprintf(str, "%d", timer);
```

in which timer is the int.

But when I build this code, I get the following warnings.

```
Type implicit declaration of function 'sprintf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]   
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'sprintf' [enabled by default]
```

what does that mean?

note:( I have included string.h and stdlib.h).

---

great, I added stdio.h to my code and now the warnings disappeared only to give me a even harder error.

undefined reference to `_sbrk'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `#include <stdio.h>` to use `sprintf()`

Comment: yes he was, and i am most greatfull. I cant even accept his anwser jet, he was TOO fast :P

Answer (score 2):

you want to make sure you also add reference to

```
stdio.h
```

[see this ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put `sprintf(str, "%d", timer)` inside a function (not on the global part of the source code).

Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char str[20];
// SPOT #1
int f() {
    sprintf(str, "%d", timer); // this won't work if placed on SPOT #1
}
```

Comment: it is inside of a function... so thats most definitly not it. :)